# while using ajax callback my whole form regenerate again

Tags: ajax

I am inserting a record in a temp table using ajax callback. but I want to clear the whole form when the data is submitted using ajax. In this code I am returning only the grid   return $form['traveler_itinerary']['temp_report'];. It only reload the grid but when i try to reset the whole fieldset $form['traveler_itinerary'], the full form regenerate again while the previous one is already there. Please guide me how to reset the form when the data is submitted using ajax.

```
    <?php

    function emp_travel_request_menu()
    {
$items  = array();
// Generate a changing number of checkboxes.
$items['emp_travel_request'] = array(
    'title' => 'Employee Travel Request',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('emp_travel_request_form'),
    'access callback' => true,
    'weight' => 1,

);

$items['emp_travel_request/hotel'] = array(
    'title' => 'Hotel Reservation',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('emp_travel_request_form'),
    'access callback' => true,
    'weight' => 2,
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
);

$items['emp_travel_request/logistics'] = array(
    'title' => 'Logistics',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('emp_travel_request_form'),
    'access callback' => true,
    'weight' => 3,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);

$items['emp_travel_request/airticket'] = array(
    'title' => 'Hotel Reservation',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('emp_travel_request_form'),
    'access callback' => true,
    'weight' => 4,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);

$items['emp_travel_request/security'] = array(
    'title' => 'Security',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('emp_travel_request_form'),
    'access callback' => true,
    'weight' => 5,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);

$items['emp_travel_request/finance'] = array(
    'title' => 'Finance',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('emp_travel_request_form'),
    'access callback' => true,
    'weight' => 6,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);



return $items;
}

 /**
 * Form manipulation through AJAX.
 *
  * AJAX-enabled select element causes replacement of a set of checkboxes
 * based on the selection.
  */
function emp_travel_request_form($form, &$form_state) {

 //Attach the CSS for the form
$form['#attached']['css'] = array(
    drupal_get_path('module', 'emp_travel_request') . '/travel_style.css',
);

//Get the list of all the employees
$user_query = db_select('users');
$user_query->fields('users', array('uid', 'name',));
$user_query->condition('name','','<>');
$user_query->condition('name','hr.admin','<>');
$user_query->condition('name','admin','<>');
$user_query->orderBy('name', 'ASC');
$user_results = $user_query->execute();

//define rows
$uid_options = array();
foreach ($user_results as $user_result) {
    $uid_options[$user_result->uid] = $user_result->name;
}

$form['travelers_info_tabs'] = array(
   '#type' => 'vertical_tabs',
);

$form['travelers_info'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Travel Request Form'),
    '#weight' => 1,
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,

);

$form['travelers_info']['all_travelers'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Traveler / Traveler\'s'),
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => $uid_options,
    //'#default_value' => $default,
    '#prefix' => '<div class="all_travelers">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'all_travelers1_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'all-travelers-div',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
    ),

);

$form['travelers_info']['reason_for_travel'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Reason for Travel'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#prefix' => '<div>',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#weight' => 2,
    '#required' => FALSE,

);

$form['traveler_itinerary'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Traveler Itinerary'),
    '#weight' => 2,
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,

);


$form['traveler_itinerary']['who_travelers'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Who'),
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="all-travelers-div">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#weight' => 2,
    '#required' => FALSE,
    '#tree' => TRUE,
);

$format = 'dd/mm/YYYY';

$form['traveler_itinerary']['travel_date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_select', // types 'date_text' and 'date_timezone' are also supported. See .inc file.
    '#title' => t('Travel Date'),
    '#default_value' => date_now(),
    '#date_format' => $format,
    '#date_label_position' => 'within', // See other available attributes and what they do in date_api_elements.inc
    '#date_increment' => 15, // Optional, used by the date_select and date_popup elements to increment minutes and seconds.
    '#date_year_range' => '-3:+3', // Optional, used to set the year range (back 3 years and forward 3 years is the default).
    '#prefix' => '<div>',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#weight' => 1,
    '#required' => FALSE,

);


$form['traveler_itinerary']['travel_from'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' =>array(
        'Islamabad' => t('Islamabad'),
        'Peshawar' => t('Peshawar'),
        'Lahore' => t('Lahore'),
        'Karachi' => t('Karachi'),
        'Quetta' => t('Quetta'),
    ),
    '#title' => t('Travel From'),
    '#empty_option' => '--Select Location--',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="travel-from-div">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#weight' => 3,
    '#required' => FALSE,

);

$form['traveler_itinerary']['travel_to'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' =>array(
        'Islamabad' => t('Islamabad'),
        'Peshawar' => t('Peshawar'),
        'Lahore' => t('Lahore'),
        'Karachi' => t('Karachi'),
        'Quetta' => t('Quetta'),
    ),
    '#title' => t('Travel To'),
    '#empty_option' => '--Select Location--',
    '#prefix' => '<div>',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#weight' => 4,
    '#required' => FALSE,

);

$form['traveler_itinerary']['mode'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Mode'),
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#options' =>array(
        'By Road' => t('By Road'),
        'By Train' => t('By Train'),
        'By Plane' => t('By Plane'),

    ),
    '#default_value' => 'By Road',
    '#prefix' => '<div>',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#weight' => 5,
    '#required' => FALSE,

);

$form['traveler_itinerary']['airport'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Airport Pick & Drop Req.'),
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#prefix' => '<div>',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#weight' => 6,
    '#required' => FALSE,

);

$form['traveler_itinerary']['acc'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Accomodation req.'),
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#prefix' => '<div>',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#weight' => 7,
    '#required' => FALSE,

);

$form['traveler_itinerary']['pickup_point'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Pickup Point'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#prefix' => '<div>',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#size' => 60,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#weight' => 8,
    '#required' => FALSE,

);


$form['traveler_itinerary']['pickup_time'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Pickup Time'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#prefix' => '<div>',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#size' => 60,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#weight' => 9,
    '#required' => FALSE,

);

//session_start();    

$form['traveler_itinerary']['travel_session_id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => session_id(),

);



//add the users to the who travelers list box
if(!empty($form_state['values']['all_travelers'])) {

    $travelers_ID = array_filter($form_state['values']['all_travelers']);

    //Get the list of selected the employees
    $user_query = db_select('users');
    $user_query->fields('users', array('uid', 'name',));
    $user_query->condition('uid', $travelers_ID, 'IN');
    $user_results = $user_query->execute();

    //add checkboxes to the who_travel fieldset
    foreach ($user_results as $user_result) {
        $form['traveler_itinerary']['who_travelers']["$user_result->uid"] = array(
            '#type' => 'checkbox',
            '#title' => $user_result->name,
            '#return_value' => $user_result->uid,
        );

    }

 }




$markup = '';



$markup = '<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Who</th>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>To</th>
        <th>Mode</th>
        <th>Airport pick & drop req.</th>
        <th>Acc.</th>
        <th>Pickup Point</th>
        <th>Pickup Time</th>
      </tr>
    </thead><tbody>';



//Adding the record to the temprery table
if(!empty($form_state['values']['travel_from']))
{
    $travel_date = !empty($form_state['values']['travel_date']) ? $form_state['values']['travel_date'] : '';
    $location_from = !empty($form_state['values']['travel_from']) ? $form_state['values']['travel_from'] : '';
    $location_to = !empty($form_state['values']['travel_to']) ? $form_state['values']['travel_to'] : '';   
    $mode_of_travel = $form_state['values']['mode'];     
    $airport_pick_drop_req = $form_state['values']['airport'];
    $accomodation_req = $form_state['values']['acc'];
    $pickup_point = !empty($form_state['values']['pickup_point']) ? $form_state['values']['pickup_point'] : '';                 
    $pickup_time = !empty($form_state['values']['pickup_time']) ? $form_state['values']['pickup_time'] : '';                    
    $travel_session_id = !empty($form_state['values']['travel_session_id']) ? $form_state['values']['travel_session_id'] : '';

    $travels_who = array_filter($form_state['values']['who_travelers']);
    foreach ($travels_who as $key => $value) {
      $travel_who_selected .=  $value . "," ;         
    }


    $updated = db_insert('travel_request_itinerary_tmp')
                ->fields(array(
                'travel_date' => $travel_date,
                'travels_who' => $travel_who_selected,
                'location_from' => $location_from,
                'location_to' => $location_to,
                'mode_of_travel' => $mode_of_travel,
                'airport_pick_drop_req' => $airport_pick_drop_req,
                'accomodation_req' => $accomodation_req,
                'pickup_point' => $pickup_point,
                'pickup_time' => $pickup_time,
                'travel_session_id' => $travel_session_id,
                ))
                ->execute();




}

//add the rows of the travel_request_itinerary_tmp based seession_id to the table
$travel_temp_query = db_select('travel_request_itinerary_tmp');
$travel_temp_query->fields('travel_request_itinerary_tmp', array(
    'travel_session_id', 
    'travel_date',
    'travels_who',
    'location_from',
    'location_to',
    'mode_of_travel',
    'airport_pick_drop_req',
    'accomodation_req',
    'pickup_point',
    'pickup_time',
    'tmp_id',
    ));

$travel_temp_query->condition('travel_session_id', session_id(), '=');
$travel_temp_results = $travel_temp_query->execute();

  //add checkboxes to the who_travel fieldset
foreach ($travel_temp_results as $travel_temp_result) {
    $markup .= '<tr>
                <td>' . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($travel_temp_result->travel_date)) . '</td>
                <td>' . get_travelers_name($travel_temp_result->travels_who) . '</td>
                <td>' . $travel_temp_result->location_from . '</td>
                <td>' . $travel_temp_result->location_to . '</td>
                <td>' . $travel_temp_result->mode_of_travel . '</td>
                <td>' . $travel_temp_result->airport_pick_drop_req = 0 || is_null($travel_temp_result->airport_pick_drop_req) ? "No" : "Yes" . '</td>
                <td>' . $travel_temp_result->accomodation_req = 0 || is_null($travel_temp_result->accomodation_req) ? "No" : "Yes" . '</td>
                <td>' . $travel_temp_result->pickup_point . '</td>
                <td>' . date ('H:i',strtotime($travel_temp_result->pickup_time)) . '</td> 
                </tr>';
}


   $markup .= '</tbody>'; 

$form['traveler_itinerary']['temp_report'] = array(
               '#markup' => '<table width="100%" border="1">'. $markup .'</table><br/><br/>',
               '#prefix' => '<div id="temp-wrapper">',
               '#suffix' => '</div>', 
               '#weight' => 10,
                 );


 $form ['traveler_itinerary']['btn_travelers']    = array(
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => t('Add Travelers'),
  '#weight' => 11,
  '#ajax' => array(
    'event' => 'click',
    'callback' => 'add_travelers_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'temp-wrapper',
    'method' => 'replace',
   ),
 );

$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
    '#weight' => 3,
);


return $form;
}

function get_travelers_name($travelers_ids){
$travelers_ids = rtrim($travelers_ids,','); 
$query = db_select('users', '');
$query->fields('users', array('name'));
$query->condition('uid', array(explode(',',$travelers_ids)), 'IN');
$results = $query->execute();

$name_array = "<ul>";    
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $name_array .= "<li>" . str_replace(".", " ", $result->name) . "</li>" ;
}
$name_array .= "</ul>";


return rtrim($name_array,', ');

}


function add_travelers_callback($form, &$form_state) {
if (!empty($form_state['executed'])) {
    $form['result'] = array(
        '#markup' => 'Done!</b>',
    );
    $form['pickup_point']['#value'] = '';
    return $form['traveler_itinerary'];
} else {
    $form['result'] = array(
        '#markup' => 'Error!</b>',
    );
}
return $form['traveler_itinerary']['temp_report'];
//$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
 //return $form['traveler_itinerary']; 
}



function all_travelers1_callback($form, $form_state) {
return $form['traveler_itinerary']['who_travelers'];
  // return $form;
}




function emp_travel_request_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```